# Xcode won't add files to source control

Tags: xcode, xcode5

when ever i add files to my project. Xcode should automatically "at least it did at one point" add it to my source control. and write a A out for it. 
now it just does this : see picture

i tried to reinstall Xcode using app-cleaner.. nothing changed there

And NO it doesn't help if i click the add files, no matter where in Xcode i click Add - nothing happens...
i'm using Github as repo
and using Xcode 5.1

i know i could just use Terminal and use git commands like : git add -A git commit -m "first init" and finally git push origin -u
but Xcode should do all this for me

[image: preview]

[image]

Comment: did you click that Add button next to "Status Unversioned"?

Comment: Yes, i also tried that. nothing happens

Comment: so if you select these files with a ?, and right click on it, you don't see an option to Add to repository? What do you see if you go to terminal, the the folder containing this project and do a 'git status' ?

Comment: i see a option for Add to repository, nothing happens if i click there. as i wrote in question. no matter where in Xcode i click add to repository or like that. nothing happens at all.
in terminal via git i can do it all. what do you want me to look for ?

Comment: when you are in your project folder (on terminal), and you do a 'git status', what does it say?

Comment: well i was working last night. so i added new files. and Xcode is still not adding them. anyway here's the output of git status : Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

 "MinBl\303\245Bog/morsSoesViewController.h"
 "MinBl\303\245Bog/morsSoesViewController.m"

Comment: Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
 modified:   BabyBogen.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
 "MinBl\303\245Bog/morsSoesViewController.h"
 "MinBl\303\245Bog/morsSoesViewController.m"

Comment: so now, try [git add morsSoesViewController.h -m "commit message"] , what happens?

Comment: error: unknown switch `m'

Comment: think it's git add -A and then git commit -m "commit message"

Comment: thats right. Does it let you do that from Terminal?

Comment: Yes i can do all that, wrote that aswell in my post

Comment: aaah, sorry I missed that last line. I'd suggest you use a different client (many people hate the Github client, but I love it). Probably you can try GitX(free) or Tower(paid) if you don't want to do it through Github client

Comment: well i rather much want Xcode to behave like it used to. an manage my files !

Comment: understandable. (haven't heard a favorable opinion of Xcode's git integration though)

Comment: i had the same problem in Xcode 10. During search on stack overflow the option for adding files has appeared in a miracle.

Answer (score 3):

If you click on 'Source Control' in the XCode menu do you see two options listed? I found that I had a .git file located in my iOS projects directory which contains all of my iOS projects. I deleted this and it fixed the problem.

I think that when you import all of your repos into SourceTree it creates a .git file in the parent folder of your repos.